# Constrained parameters in least square curve fitting

Tags: curves, least-squares

I have some data points that need to be fit to the curve defined by

$$y(x)=\frac{k}{(x+a)^2} - b$$

I have considered that it can be done by the least squares method. However, the analytical solution gives me a negative $a$, so it puts the first point on the left branch of this hyperbola and I need all the points to fit to the right branch, thus $a$ must be positive. All my points have positive $x$ and $y$ is non-increasing.

Is there any way to add this type of constraint to analytical solution?

I would also kindly appreciate any links to related and/or useful information on iterative numerical solution. I need to program everything manually for my mobile app, so I can't use any external software or libraries.

Comment: @Hyyy6 : I wonder if your equation $y(x)=\frac{k}{(x+a)2} - b$ means $$y(x)=\frac{k}{2(x+a)} - b$$ or $$y(x)=\frac{k}{(x+a)^2} - b$$ Would you mind give an example of data for which the trouble occurs.

Comment: @JJacquelin Sorry, my bad, it's the latter one. In the first case 1/2 could go into $k$ parameter anyway. The data points example is: x = {0, 1, 2, 3}, y = {-23, -32, -38, -40}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that the OP is looking for a conventional method of regression, the present answer would be not convenient. This is why I post it as a distinct answer.

The calculus below is ultra simple since there is no iteration and no need for initial guessed values.

[image]

Numerical example :

[image]

Result :

[image]

$\textbf{Comment :}$

At first sight, while comparing the approximate values of parameters $a,b,k$ , it seems that the present result is not close to the previous result obtained with a classical non-linear regression.

In fact the curves drawn on the respective graphs are almost undistinguishable. Moreover the respective standard deviations are close : $0.403$ for the first method compared to $0.441$ for the second.

This is an unexpected good result because in case of small number of points the numerical integration introduces additional deviations. (The numerical integration is involved in the computation of the $S_i$ ).

$\textbf{For information :}$

In this non-conventional method, instead of the fitting of the function where the parameters act non-linearly, one fit an integral equation where the same parameters act linearly. The original function is a solution of the integral equation. This transforms the non-linear regression into a linear regression. For more explanation and examples : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales

In the present case a convenient integral equation is :
$$ay+2bx-xy-\int y\;dx=\text{constant}$$
One observe that a parameter $c$ seems to disappear but is in fact hidden into the constant. That is why an additional linear regression is necessary to compute the missing parameter.

Of course the criteria of fitting is not the same in the conventional methods. If a specific criteria is specified in the wording of the problem, one cannot avoid a non-liner regression adapted for the specific criteria. In that case one can start the iterative process from the values of parameters provided by the above regression with integral equation. This avoids the uncertain search for good "guessed' values of parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much for such an easy to understand and thorough answer!

Comment: You are welcome. But if it is an academic exercise, don't forget that the regression with integral equation is not a standard method. The criteria of fitting is not exactly the same as in the usual least squares fitting.

Comment: *"not standard"*, I agree but *fascinating* !

Answer (score 1):

In any manner, your model is nonlinear with respect to parameters. So, why not to rewrite it as
$$y(x)=\frac{k}{(x+\alpha^2)2} - b$$

Comment: Hi Claude ! Always so pragmatic. Cheers !

Comment: Why is the coefficient $2$ in that position?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo. Because in the initial question (have a look to the edits), there was not a square. Cheers -:)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see any difficulty with the your data points  x = {0, 1, 2, 3}, y = {-23, -32, -38, -40}.

With least squares fitting my result is shown on the figure below. The computed value of $a$ is positive as expected.

If you obtain a negative $a$ or other aberrant results this is probably due to the software that you use.

Since the regression is non-linear, the usual softwares proceed with iterative calculus which requires initial values for the sought parameters. The computation of preliminary approximates of the parameters is the main weakness of the softwares. If the "guessed" starting values are not good enough the further iterative computation may lead to incorrect results.

Of course I cannot be sure that this is the true explanation of the trouble in your case of calculus without more information about the algorithm of your software, especially for the approximation of the starting values of the parameters.

[image]

IN ADDITION after the discussion in comments :

So, you want to write your own program. I suggest a simplified way for non-linear regression in case of the function 
$$y=\frac{k}{(x+a)^2}-b$$
Start with a guessed value $a=a_0$ .
From the data $(x_k, y_k)$ compute a new data $(X_k,y_k)$ with 
$$X_k=\frac{1}{(x_k+a_0)^2}$$
Then make a linear regression for the unknown parameters $k,b$ with respect to the linear function 
$$y=kX-b$$
Compute a corrected value of $a_0$ and iterate the process.

Of course it is possible to proceed "by hand" with successive corrections of $a_0$ by trial and error but this should be tiresome.

Comment: The thing is, I cannot use any 3rd party software, I need to program it myself. That's why the question was about the algorithm itself and not about software. Still appreciate your answer, unfortunately, cannot upvote it because of lack of reputation.

Comment: Don't worry about the upvote. It doesn't matter. If the software has to be implemented by yourself with your own algorithm, this is a different question. I didn't understood that. If you need help, you should show what you have done and where exactly you faced a difficulty.

Comment: The algorithms for non-linear linear least squares fitting are not simple. The basic theory can be found for example in : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NonlinearLeastSquaresFitting.html .

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising! I'm still struggling with understanding the last bit with computing $da_0$ using this equation:
$dy = −2\frac{k}{(x_k+a)^3}da_0$
I don't quite get what function are we differentiating (I assume it's the first one with estimated parameters) by the parameter $a$, and then at which point do we do that in order to compute the $da_0$. And to be honest I do not understand how to compute it given this variation equation.
Of course I'll try investigating on that issue further if you consider not breaking down everything into basics, still massive thanks!

Comment: It's not simple. The differential is only an hint to understand the principle. Note that there was a typo (no indice $k$ for $x$). One have as many $da_0$ as they are points. Roughly take an average. In fact, this simplified method is for lazy people. It is better to learn and apply the general method explained in the referenced paper. For even more lazy people, I will  add to my answer another method (non-conventional) which is not iterative and not requiring initial guess.

Comment: I deleted the hint for a simplified non-linear regression which might confuse you. If it is an academic exercise it is better to fully learn the general method instead of a simple patch-up of no general use.